# $W \subset M_{3x3} $ find $T:M_{3x3}(R) \to M_{3x3}(R)$ such that $W \subset ImT$ and $kerT$ is subpace of symmetric matrices with diag($0$)

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
W = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
b & -a & 3a+b\\ 
c & 0 & a+2c\\ 
-3c & c & b
\end{pmatrix} \in M_3(R)), a,b,c \in R \right \}
$$

Give an example for $T:M_{3x3}(R) \to M_{3x3}(R)$ such that $W \subset ImT$ and $kerT$ is the subspace of the symmetrical matrices in $M_3(R)$ that there diagonal is $0's$

Im trying to build such a transformation, trying things, guessing, is there is a way to do it smarter? or realy just trying to build one from trial and error?

---

### *EDIT: What i understood in the end from others

### *The idea:

If we find 9 linear idependent matrices in $T$ that we are looking for, and we will know there projection ot the $ImT$ we will be able to represent a general matrix in the transformation like this:
D(T) - domain of T, Im(T) - Image of T

Let:
$$G \in D(T)$$

Let $B_T$ be a basis for $T$ such that:

$$
B_T = \left \{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6,b_7,b_8,b_9 \right \}
$$

Therefore, for scalars $a_i \in R | 1 \leq i \leq 9$

$$G = a_1b_1+a_2b_2 +...+a_9b_9$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$T(G) = T(a_1b_1+a_2b_2 +...+a_9b_9)$$

But, from linear transformation properties we know that:

$$T(v,u) = T(v) + T(u), v,u \in D(T )$$

Therefore:
$$T(a_1b_1+a_2b_2 +...+a_9b_9) = T(a_1b_1)+T(a_2b_2)+...+T(a_9b_9)$$

Now, using $T(av) = aT(v), a\in R, v \in D(T)$ we get:

$$T(a_1b_1)+T(a_2b_2)+...+T(a_9b_9) = a_1T(b_1)+a_2T(b_2)+...+a_9T(b_3)$$

So if we know each $b_i$ and its tranformation, namely, $T(bi)$ we will be able to represent $T(G)$ for the general matrix in the domain - namely, we will find the transformation $T$.

---

We want to find a basis for the transformation, by finding the basis we would be able to represent the tranformation from an element in the domain to an element in the $ImT$ - because every element in the domain will have a representation in the $ImT$ as a linear combination of the basis.

In order to find a basis for $M_{3x3}R$ we will look for $9$ linear independent matrices that satisfies the conditions for $T$.

We can get $3$ matrices from $kerT$.

From the definition of $kerT$, the basis for those symmetric matrices will be:

$$
b_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, 
b_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0\end{pmatrix}
b_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B_{kerT} = \left \{ b_1,b_2 ,b_3  \right \}
$$

Because its $kerT$ we can detemine that $T(b_1) = T(b_2) = T(b_3) = 0$

We have left to find 6 linear independent matrices and there projection to $ImT$ in order to define the transformation.

We can represent $W$ as a linear combination of 3 matrices which build him.

$$
W = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}0&-a&3a \\ 0&0&a \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}b&0&b \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&b\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0 \\ c&0&2c \\ -3c&c&0\end{pmatrix} \right \}
$$

Present by the coordinates we get:
$$
W = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&3 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 1&0&2 \\ -3&1&0\end{pmatrix} \right \}
$$

We will write it as: 
$$
W = \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}
$$

And define:

$$
T(w_1) = W, T(w_2) = W, T(w_3) = W
$$

Now, we need 3 more independent matrices and there corresponding transformation.

We will pick 3 independent matrices (it will be comfortable to use the standard basis and take from there) so:

$$
e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
e_5 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
e_9 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

And define that they transform to the them-selves, so:

$$
T(e_1) = e_1, T(e_5) = e_5, T(e_9) = e_9.
$$

So now we can represent the general case. 
Again, define: 
$$G \in D(T), a_i \in R$$
$$
G = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3 + a_4w_1+a_5w_2+a_6w_3+a_7e_1+a_8a_5+a_9e_9
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
T(G) = a_1T(b_1)+a_2T(b_2)+...+a_9T(e_9) = 0+0+...a_4w_1+...+a_9e_9
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
v \in D(T) \Rightarrow T(v) = \begin{pmatrix}
a_5+a_7 & -a_4 & 3a_4+a_5\\ 
a_6 & a_8 & a_4+2a_6\\ 
-3a_6 & a_6 & a_5+a_9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\Downarrow
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ 
a_4 & a_5 & a_6\\ 
a_7 & a_8 & a_9
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{T} \begin{pmatrix}
a_5+a_7 & -a_4 & 3a_4+a_5\\ 
a_6 & a_8 & a_4+2a_6\\ 
-3a_6 & a_6 & a_5+a_9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $W$ is $3$-dimensional, and $\ker T$ has codimension $3$.  Find a basis of $W$ and a basis of $\ker T$ and extend the latter to basis of $M_{3\times 3}(R)$.

Comment: Sorry but i have just started linear transformations and i dont realy understand the logic you say. To find a basis for W and $ketT$ and do Union between them? B(W) U B(ketT)? and thats will give me what?...

Comment: Each member of the basis of $\ker T$  is mapped to $0$.  Each other member of the basis of $M_{3\times 3}(R)$ is mapped to a member of the basis of $W$.